# Terminate Program On -1 -1 input not working

Tags: java

I'm doing some ICPC programming problems for fun this one is Collatz. I've gotten an output that fits the expected output correctly. But I've been having problems getting the program to end when it comes to the -1 -1 input as desired.

Sample Input

```
3 100
34 100
75 250
27 2147483647
101 304
101 303
-1 -1
```

Expected Output

```
Case 1: A = 3, limit = 100, number of terms = 8 

Case 2: A = 34, limit = 100, number of terms = 14 

Case 3: A = 75, limit = 250, number of terms = 3  

Case 4: A = 27, limit = 2147483647, number of terms = 112

Case 5: A = 101, limit = 304, number of terms = 26 

Case 6: A = 101, limit = 303, number of terms = 1
```

Java Code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Integer;

public class Collatz {
    private static int caseNumber = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(in.hasNext()) {
            caseNumber++;
            int a = in.nextInt();
            Integer limit = in.nextInt();
            if(a == -1 && limit == -1)
                break;
            int numberOfTerms = 0;
            for(Integer value = a; value != 1; numberOfTerms++){
                if(value%2 == 0){
                    value /= 2;
                }else{
                    value = 3 * value + 1;
                }
                if(limit < value)
                    break;
            }
            numberOfTerms +=1;
            System.out.println("Case " + caseNumber + ": A = " + a + ", limit = "
                    + limit + ", number of terms = " + numberOfTerms);
            System.out.println();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the actual output you are getting. Then we can guess where it may be stucking?

Comment: this is actually giving me the correct output the problem I'm having is the the program isn't terminating.

Comment: I'm not [having any trouble](http://ideone.com/e7Me9) with your code.

Comment: This works fine for me (and terminates) Exactly how are your running it? Have you tried adding debug statements to see how many times iterate the while loop etc?

Comment: It does seem to be working for me now but it still isn't terminating unless I hit enter after everything runs

Answer (score 0):

Running the code in Eclipse (3.7.2) and entering values in the console window, it runs fine and terminate as expected. (i.e. when '-1' is entered twice)

Possible causes for the program not terminating:

1. Scanner converts bytes into characters based on the system's default charset.  Could your system charset be causing '-1' to be converted into something other than the expected value?
2. Could the manner you're using to enter the '-1' values be adding a trailing character or characters to the input stream that is causing the Scanner to read a value other than -1?

Try adding print statements after each `in.nextInt()` call to see what value is being produced.